# set_intersection error when computing the intersection between two sets

Tags: c++, stl

```
std::set<int> m{1,2, 4};
std::set<int> n{2,3, 4};
std::set<int> mn;
std::set<int>::iterator it;
it=set_intersection(m.begin(), m.end(),
                    n.begin(), n, end()
                    mn.begin());   //This part is not correct
for(int i : mn) cout<< i <<" ";
```

It seems the last parameter used in `set_intersection` is not correct. I tried `inserter` or `back_inserter`, but neither worked.

Comment: Is this *really* your [mcve]?

Comment: There is a perfect example at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection

Answer (score 4):

```
std::set_intersection(m.begin(), m.end(),
                      n.begin(), n.end(),
                      std::inserter(mn, mn.begin()));
```

Note that you can't assign the result to a `std::set<int>::iterator` because the return type is actually an `insert_iterator`.